# Basic Numbering Question Using amsthm

Tags: formatting, numbering, theorems, amsthm

I'm trying to learn basic usage of amsthm.

Within a book chapter or an article section, I want each use of any theorem-like environment to augment the numbering, like

> 1.1 Theorem blah blah
>
> 1.2 Proposition cha cha
>
> 1.3 Lemma mah mah
>
> 1.4 Theorem da da

This is the numbering style used, e.g., in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

The default behavior is instead

> 1.1 Theorem blah blah
>
> 1.1 Proposition cha cha
>
> 1.1 Lemma mah mah
>
> 1.2 Theorem da da

How do I get what I want?

Comment: How do you declare your theorems, propositions, lemmas?

Comment: with e.g., \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] in the preamble, then \begin{theorem}[Pythagoras] $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{theorem}  in the body.

Comment: For the other environments, try, say, `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}`  and similarly for proposition.

Comment: It works. If you make this an answer I will select it.

Comment: Needless. I'm sure there already exists such answers, albeit I don't know where they are.